# Is HTML source viewed in Firefox the same as original source?

Tags: html, firefox, view

Does Firefox's "view source" option display the same HTML page code that I would obtain by opening the HTML file in the server's file system? (e.g with notepad), or is it modified?

Comment: If the DOM tree hasn't been modified by javascript code, and the page wasn't generated by a server-side application, it should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not de original source code. Firefox parses the source code before like beautifulsoup does.

You can view the original source code in linux with wget url.

Answer (score 1):

Besides that it has syntax highlighting and the urls are clickable, the view source has the original content.

So if you view source and copy the whole thing and paste it in notepad is the same result as opening the actual webpage in notepad.

Answer (score 1):

If you use FireBug, the source is modified, otherwise Firefox shows the original source

Answer (score -1):

The 'view source' will show the actual source code, as sent by the server. Formatting is left as is, but urls will be clickable and open a new window with the resource referred to.

The 'view generated source' will show the source code as currently displayed on the page, thus containing modifications to the DOM after the page was sent, usually done with Javascript.